# gradle: find to which project does a file belong

Tags: gradle

Let's consider this sample multi gradle project structure

```
build.gradle
|-- project-a
|   |-- build.gradle
|   +-- project-a-b
|       |--  src
|       |    |
|       |    +-- test.java
|       |
|       +-- build.gradle
+-- project-c
    |-- build.gradle
    +-- src
        +-- test2.java
```

And let's say from git changelog I have changed files:

```
project-a/project-a-b/src/test.java
project-c/src/test2.java
```

I need to find out to which project they belong

```
project-a/project-a-b/src/test.java -> project-a-b
project-c/src/test2.java -> project-c
```

Is there something that gradle offers out of the box (e.g. give filename, get nearest project)? Googling did not help, but maybe the question was wrong.

I know I could just put filesystem in a tree structure and traverse it

Comment: Well, the question is, how do you define "belongs to"? Does it have to be in one of the sourcesets, does it have to be in the project folder, ...?

Comment: In the project folder. Basically algo would look like this: from change source file, walk tree upwords, for each parent node check if it has direct child build.gradle, stop at first found.

Comment: That algo would be flawed, or only working if you know it is like that for your build. Generally the project dirs are freely configurable and don't have to be hierarchical in the file system. Additionally having a `build.gradle` for a project is purely optional.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want:

```
def file = file('your/path')
def project
while (file.parentFile != null) {
    file = file.parentFile
    project = rootProject.allprojects.findAll { it.projectDir == file }
    if (project) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd traverse up the parent hierarchy of the file until I found a project dir match

```
public Project getOwningProject(File findMe) {
    Map<String, Project> map = [:]
    allprojects.each { Project p ->
        map[p.projectDir.absolutePath] = p
    }
    File dir = findMe.directory ? findMe : findMe.parentFile
    while (dir != null) {
       Project p = map[dir.absolutePath]
       if (p) return p
       dir = dir.parentFile
    } 
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following defines a `findFile` task for each project (using `sourceSets`), consolidated in the root `build.gradle` (full [example here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/egg_StackOverflow_47691416)).

```
subprojects { project ->
    apply plugin: 'java'

    task findFile() {
        doLast {
            def targetFile = project.targetFile
            project.sourceSets.main.java.each { file -> 
                if (file.absolutePath.contains(targetFile)) {
                    println "TRACER found ${targetFile} in project: ${project.name}"
                }
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

It currently only searches for one file, but that could easily be adopted for more. Example usage:

```
gradle findFile -PtargetFile=project-a/project-a-b/src/main/java/TestAB.java

TRACER found project-a/project-a-b/src/main/java/TestAB.java in project: project-a-b
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it might depend on criteria for `belongs to`...

Given above example the owning project is named by the parent directory of the `src` directory. I.e. you can see it directly in your Git changeset/changelog.